# Using function with parameter in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this route:

```
Route::post('/quiz/category/{$name}', 'playquiz@category');
```

the category function of playquiz controller is:

```
public function category($name)
  {
        $ch = DB::select('select * from quiz where category="$name" and level="1"');
        return View('quiz.index',['quiz'=>$ch]);     

 }
```

why is this

```
<a href="{{url('quiz/category/geography')}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Geography</a>
```

link not supposed to work? How can this be done?

`quiz.index` view:

```
@foreach ($quiz as $q)

    {{ $q->qid }}.  
    {{ $q->question }}<br>
    <input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$q->qid."]' value='1'>     
    {{ $q->opt1 }}<br>
    <input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$q->qid."]' value='2'>     
    {{ $q->opt2 }}<br>
    <input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$q->qid."]' value='3'>    
    {{ $q->opt3 }}<br>
    <input type='radio' name='mycheck[".$q->qid."]' value='4'>   
    {{ $q->opt4 }}<br><br>

@endforeach
```

Comment: When you say that something does not work - we have absolutely **NO IDEA** what it means that it does not work. You need to explain everything, include debug messages, logged messages, explain what you tried, what you need, what you get. Otherwise, you're asking people to make an educated guess. For example, first thing that I'd try is viewing the source of the page to see what `<a href="....` actually contains.

Comment: If memory serves correctly, `{{url('quiz/category/geography')}}` should match the same route you have given in your `routes.php`: `/quiz/category/{$name}` So: `{{url('/quiz/category/geography')}}`

Comment: If you are getting `MethodNotAllowed Exception` it is because your route is `POST` and an anchor (`<a>` tag) will produce a `GET` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your route to

```
//Check removing of $ from name
Route::get('/quiz/category/{name}', 'playquiz@category');
```

You are using link which is actually a GET request.

You query is also wrong. This is correct one.

```
public function category($name)
{
    $ch = DB::select("select * from quiz where category='$name' and level='1'");
    return View('quiz.index',['quiz'=>$ch]);     

}
```

Or You can also do this

```
DB::table('quiz')->where('name',$name)->get(); 
DB::table('quiz')->where('name',$name)->first();
```

first will return a collection of all quizzes with name and later returns only one model. You can choose any according to requirement.

Comment: ok, that link is routes to the controller which returns to the view. and the view is not fetching data from database,

Answer (score -1):

Make your Quiz model, ensure that it extends model. Something like this:

```
Routes:
Route::post('/quiz/category', 'playquiz@category');

<?php namespace App;

class Quiz extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'Quiz'; //table name
    protected $fillable = ['mass assignable table fields'];

}
```

And then your function to query:

use App\Quiz;

```
public function category(Request $request)
  {
        $ch = Quiz::whereCategory($request->name)->whereLevel(1)->get();
        return View('quiz.index')->with(compact('ch');     
 }
```

View:

```
<form method="POST" action="/quiz/category">
     <input type="hidden" value="geography" name="name">
     <button>Geography</button>
</form>
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Your `Quiz` model is named `User`. I'm guessing a copy/paste error.

Comment: Nice catch! I thought I changed it ^^ Was a copy and paste right from my current project :P